# php pdo select query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm new to php PDO, i've made a query to select users in db and display them in a html table but i get no result, and there is no error message. `print_r($connexion)` returns `PDO Object ( )`

here is the code. thanks for your help!

## connexion to db //connexion.php

```
function connexion(){

try {
   $dns = 'mysql:host = localhost; dbname = pruf';
   $utilisateur = 'root';
   $motDePasse = '';
   $connexion = new PDO($dns, $utilisateur, $motDePasse, array(
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
   ));
} 

catch (Exception $ex) {
   echo "connexion à Mysql impossible", $ex->getMessage();
   die('ok');
}

return $connexion;
```

## query file //searchInvite.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"
</head>
<html>
<table border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td>Nom</td>
        <td>Prenom</td>
        <td>Fonction</td>
        <td>Titre</td>
        <td>Adresse</td>
</tr>

<?php
    require_once 'connexion.php';

   $connexion = connexion();
   print_r($connexion); 
   $query = "SELECT nom, prenom, fonction, titre_grade, adr_pro_voie FROM invite ORDER BY id LIMIT 0 , 30";

   $stmt = $connexion->prepare($query);


   $stmt->execute();

   while ($enregistrement = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $enregistrement->nom; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $enregistrement->prenom; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $enregistrement->fonction; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $enregistrement->titre_grade ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $enregistrement->adr_pro_voie; ?></td>
    </tr>


<?php 
}

?>
 </table>
```

Comment: You don't have an `:id` placeholder in your query.

Comment: Where' **:id** in the query ?

Comment: I've never seen a $dsn containing spaces before ...  $dns = 'mysql:host = localhost; dbname = pruf'; Try:  $dns = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruf'; - just an idea.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying i've removed the spaces, i got the table displayed, but inside each row, i have this error message: "Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\sqlquery\SearchInvites.php on line 40"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm Here is your code:

**PHP Code [index.php]:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" </head>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1px">
    <tr>
        <td>Nom</td>
        <td>Prenom</td>
        <td>Fonction</td>
    </tr>
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
$DBH = connection();
# creating the statement
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT nom, prenom, fonction, titre_grade, adr_pro_voie FROM invite ORDER BY id LIMIT 0 , 30");
# setting the fetch mode  
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
# run the query
if ( $STH->execute()){
# showing the results  
while($enregistrement = $STH->fetch()) {  
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $enregistrement->nom; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $enregistrement->prenom; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $enregistrement->fonction; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $enregistrement->titre_grade ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $enregistrement->adr_pro_voie; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php }
}else {
    // if not run pdo statement send error
    $error = $STH->errorInfo();
    echo $error[2];
} ?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Code [connection.php]**

```
function connection() {
    // try catch block start
    try {
        // use native pdo class and connect
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruf", 'root', '', array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
        )); 
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        // get pdo error and pass on error method
        die("ERROR in establish connection: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $DBH;
}
```

**Some suggestions:**

```
 1. Check your DB name
 2. Check your user name
 3. Check your password
 4. Check your server
 5. Check if user privilege access database
 6. Check table name, try to dry run query.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i've removed the $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); cause i want to retrieve all the users not just one particular id. now the table is displayed, but inside each row, i have this error message: "Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\sqlquery\SearchInvites.php on line 40" –

Comment: @Albee: Check my updated answer with error handling.

Comment: your welcome :) you can also use PDO Class Wrapper https://github.com/neerajsinghsonu/PDO_Class_Wrapper

Comment: Allright, i'll try that.